# Can't create MongoDB entries associated with logged in user

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, express

I'm trying to print a list of all database entries created by a particular user. I'm logging in users to the Express.js app with Passport so every new user gets an _id in Mongo when they register.

Under each User in Mongo the entries property is created from the schema but it's just an empty array, even after they create an entry - it doesn't associate with the user that made it.

I’m using the following model schemas:

For Entries:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var entrySchema = new Schema({
  date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  hours: Number,
  income: Number,
  user_id: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Entries', entrySchema);
```

And for User:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    userName: String,
    password: String,
    entries: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'EntryModel'
        }
    ]
});

UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

The form in the view:

```
<form method="POST" action="/table">
   inputs...
</form>
<button type="submit" ng-model="newEntry" ng-click="postEntry(user._id)">Submit</button>
```

In my Angular controller:

```
$scope.postEntry = function(id, index, entry){

    $http.post('/api/entry/' + _id, {
            date: entry.date,
            hours: entry.hours,
            income: entry.income,
            user_id: entry._id
        })
        .then(function(res, status){
            console.log(res.data);
        })
        .catch(function(err){
            alert('There was a problem saving your entry: ' + err.data);
        });
    // then update page with associated entries
    $http.get('/api/entry/:id').then(function(response){
        $scope.entries = response.data;
    });
}
```

And my API:

```
app.post('/table/:id', urlencodedParser, function(req, res){
    var newEntry = Entries({
      date: req.body.date,
      hours: req.body.hours,
      income: req.body.income,
      id: req.body.id
    });
    // and save to Mongo
    newEntry.save(function(err){
        if (err) throw err;
        res.render('table/:id');
    });
});
```

I'm pretty sure the form should pick up the user _id but it doesn't appear to be.

Comment: You have `$http.post('/api/entry/' + _id,` but your function signature calls it  just `id` without the "underscore" `_`. Here `function(id, index, entry)`

Comment: @NeilLunn Sadly that wasn't the issue. Just a typo.